# Why a string have the same size applying gzcompress and gzuncompress?

Tags: php, mysql, string, algorithm, compression

I have a mysql table with a field and I don't have the permission to modify the table schema.

```
content varchar (255) not null
```

is there anyway to insert string with more size(greater than 255) to this field. I dont care how its stored(compressed or encoded). I want to retrieve the uncompressed one if it is compressed.

things I tried

```
gzcompress();

base64_encode();

<?php
$compressed   = gzcompress('asdasdwq3eryt238774284873246827364872687342873rweuydfgjshdbfdgfgs', 9);
$uncompressed = gzuncompress($compressed);
echo $compressed.'---'.strlen($compressed);
echo "<br />";
echo $uncompressed.'----'.strlen($uncompressed);

//BOTH ARE SAME IN SIZE
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gzcompress compresses the given string using the ZLIB data format. For details on the ZLIB compression algorithm see the document [ZLIB Compressed Data Format Specification version 3.3](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html) (RFC 1950)

You can read one explanation of how ZLIB works in:

> http://www.zlib.net/feldspar.html

```
<?php
$compressed   = gzcompress(' This function compresses the given string using the ZLIB data format. For details on the ZLIB compression algorithm see the document "» ZLIB Compressed Data Format Specification version 3.3" (RFC 1950). ', 9);
$uncompressed = gzuncompress($compressed);
echo $compressed.'---'.strlen($compressed);
echo "<br />";
echo $uncompressed.'----'.strlen($uncompressed);

?>
```

Comment: but both are same in length

Comment: In my example compressed are 155 and uncompressed 205, if you want know why, you should read the RFC 1950.

Comment: @coolguy I edit with other link with the explanation, I don't copy here because is large.